# How would I count all pairs in a list when they are all the same?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to count all pairs of numbers in a list. A pair is just  two numbers  that are the same. My current code looks like this.

```
def pairs(lst):
    lst.sort()
    count = 0
    for x in range(len(lst)):
        if x+1 < len(lst):
            if lst[x] == lst[x+1]:
                count +=1
    return count

pairs([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

What do I need to change to be able to have it count each pair of 1's?

Comment: How many pairs do you expect in that list?

Comment: Expects 10 pairs

Comment: that's what [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) does, `len(list(itertools.combinations([1,1,1,1,1], 2)))`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the function gives the wrong value is that it is taking each item in the list and checking if the next value matches it. This will double count all non-endpoint values. Also looping with conditional statements is inefficient. It may be better to think of the problem as the sum of modulo 2 of the count of each distinct item in the list.

---

### Try this:

**Include incomplete pairs**

```
import math

def count_pairs(a_list):
    counter=0
    for x in set(a_list):
        counter += math.ceil(lst.count(x)/2)
    print(counter)
```

**Include only complete pairs**

```
import math

def count_pairs(a_list):
    counter=0
    for x in set(a_list):
        counter += math.floor(lst.count(x)/2)
    print(counter)
```

**Example:**

```
lst=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,5]

count_pairs(lst)
```

---

**Output 1**

```
11
```

**Output 2**

```
7
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
list = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
list.sort

# remove last element if len(list) is odd
if ( len(list) % 2 != 0 ) :
    list.pop()

c = 0

# create an `iter` object to simplify comparisons
it = iter(list)
for x1 in it:
    x2 = next(it)
    if ( x1 == x2 ):
        c += 1
print(c)
```

It wasn't clear to me if you only want "1", if this is the case, introduce a check for x1 or x2 greater than 1 and break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def count_pairs(lst):
    ' Using generator with Walrus operator '
    return sum(cnt*(cnt-1)//2 for element in set(lst) if (cnt:=lst.count(element)))
```

**Test**

```
print(count_pairs([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))                       # Output: 10
print(count_pairs([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,5])) # Output: 25
```

**Explanation**

> The number of pairs of a number in the list is found by:
>
> - count the frequency of the number in the list
> - counting its combinations taking 2 at a time (i.e. for frequency k, combinations = k*(k-1)//2
>   We sum the pairs count for each unique number in list (i.e. set(lst))

For clarity, the oneliner solution can be expanded to the following.

```
def count_pairs(lst):
    cnt = 0
    for element in set(lst):
        frequency = lst.count(element)          # frequency of element
        cnt += frequency * (frequency - 1) //2  # accumulate count of pairs of element
        
    return cnt
```